# How can I run the Spring Tools Suite(STS) in linux mint if I also have installed eclipse indigo 3.8?

Tags: spring-tool-suite, eclipse-indigo, linux-mint

I have tried to run STS as a plugin in indigo but it doesn't let me install it with every updating url I found. So I downloaded it separately(the 3.7.0 version) and put the unzipped files under /opt. But when I try to open it I get an error

> An error has occurred. See the log file
>   /home/usr_name/.eclipse/org.springsource.sts_3.7.0.RELEASE_1662593288_linux_gtk_x86/configuration/1440782618902.log.

And that content is here: http://pastebin.com/8m2A2HLF

Can I run them both separately? Do I need another eclipse to also get the spring tool suite?

Comment: it looks like you are trying to run STS with a JDK6, but STS 3.7.0 requires JDK7 to run.

Comment: I did change the jdk to 7 and it runs now, setting it system wide to 7. Any chance you'd also know why I can't see the "dynamic web module" in project facets? :D

Comment: I am not sure about the exact setting that you have here. If you create a dynamic web project, it should have the facet. On what kind of project are you looking for the facet?

Comment: I uninstalled it again, it didn't provide me with what I needed, do you know what version of eclipse(helios, juno etc) would allow installation of STS directly from market place without a hitch? I hate it when I wonder in the dark like this.

Comment: The marketplace entry for STS is configured to work with various Eclipse versions, although I would recommend to run Eclipse Mars GA and install STS into that version. But what exactly are you missing from the STS 3.7.0 distribution on Eclipse 4.5 that a plain Eclipse 4.5 provides?

Comment: When I right click on a project I cannot see the "Convert to faceted form" option. I would need a dynamic web module facet. Can't find the plugin to install to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem was that I installed eclipse using the built-in Software Manager, after I uninstalled everything related to eclipse from the manager, STS worked without errors.
The problem with faceted forms was that it doesn't show it in the project explorer view, it worked when I had the package explorer view opened.
Yet another issue I had was with the built in servers. If you remove them but use the same old workspace location STS won't add them again unless you use a fresh workspace(new, neve-before-used-as-workspace folder).
It was annoying but in the end it works.